# Trivial representation of a maximal torus

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let G be a connected compact Lie group and $T\subset G$ a maximal torus. For an irreducible representation $V_\lambda$ of $G$, the multiplicity of the trivial representation of $T$ in $V_\lambda$ is given by the Kostant formula
\begin{equation}
\sum_{w\in W}(-1)^{\ell(w)}p(w(\lambda+\rho)-\rho).
\end{equation}
Under what assumptions can we get the multiplicity to be positive?

Comment: You need the restriction to the centre to be trivial. This is obviously a necessary condition, but I think it's also sufficient.